# how can I search for folders ending in certain characters in Finder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, spotlight, search

Executing a Finder search for folders seems limited to searching for folder names beginning with the search term. I can't search for folder names only using a characters in the middle or end. I'm having to resort to using the find command from Terminal. Any way around this? Below is a sample folder and multiple search attempts:

[image: folder with all subfolders]
[image: searching for "son" does not return anything, even though subfolders ending in "son" exist]

This is my first post here so I can only post two images, apparently. I have an additional screen shot showing a search for "jo" which indeed reveals every subfolder beginning with "jo". I have a fourth screen shot showing that a search for "bert" fails to return "robertson" "colbertson" etc. Those searches were both name-based searches with the same "kind" restriction to folders only.

What's up with this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. - feel free to upload the image and post it as a comment. Someone else can edit it in for you if it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Finder** try using this:

```
Kind is Folder
Name ends with son
```

This should display all folders ending with "son".

Try also, `begins with` and `contains` for similar searches.

[image: Folder name search Finder]

Comment: Omg... well, that works, so thank you. But why is the behavior different between files and folders? I've never had to specify "ends with" when searching for a file ending in "son". I just search for "son" and it works. But it doesn't work with folders.

Comment: Good subject for [Apple Feedback.](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a way to get variables in spotlight, but I *must* be misinformed since that seems so useful to not implement.

That being said, I use terminal and `mdfind` to parse spotlight like you have all the time.

```
mdfind "kMDItemFSName == '*son' && kMDItemKind == 'Folder'"
```

That will show you all folders ending in `son` and you might want to grep for the "sample names" folder name to replicate the search you have illustrated or use the `-onlyin` command:

```
mdfind -onlyin dir "kMDItemFSName == '*son' && kMDItemKind == 'Folder'"
```

You can drag the folder into terminal to get a properly escaped name with spaces encoded and then paste that in place of `dir`

Comment: Whoah. Good to know. Thank you. Definitely faster than using find. Would still love to be able to do it directly from Finder...

Comment: Wow! Drag into terminal - thank you for that!