# Search for ALL large files and folders (not just some) using Finder (not third-party)

Tags: finder, search

I am looking for space! I would like to search for all large folders and files. I found [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/224812/143729) but so far my searches failed to show some of the large files, including a `.pkg` file that was in my home directory (the 'house' icon). I just use "normal" finder, and then with the controls - where I am trying to find a way to say `size > 100MB` or something to that effect. But I don't even see size.

I also can not see how to display all folders on my computer where again `folder size > 100MB`. Are these possible using the Finder controls?

**edit:** To address the comments I've added an additional example. It's the selective file type that's bothering me. Here I create some files with python and look with Finder. Finder decides that I should not know about two of the files because the "Kind" is "Document". If I display the folder, they are there, but Finder won't show them if I'm searching.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

y = [3,1,5,2,0]

np.save("TestDifferent", y)

with open("TestDifferent.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(y, outfile)

with open("TestDifferent.txt", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(y))

with open("TestDifferent.weird", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(y))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(y)
plt.savefig("TestDifferent")
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image: screen shot 1 of Finder]

[image: screen shot 2 of Finder]

Comment: Have you clicked the **Kind** list box and selected **Other...** and then select a different search attribute, e.g. **File Size** or **Logical size**?

Comment: Thanks @user3439894! I've added two screenshots and modified the wording of the question. Briefly, I would like a list of `all files > 100MB` in one place, without regard to file type. The `.pkg` is just an example of a file that it is leaving out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to search for folders by file size. The combined size of all files and folders contained in a folder is computed on the fly by Finder when you ask for it.

For normal Finder windows, you can enable the option to “Calculate all sizes” in View > View Options. That option is not available for search results.

What you can do is search for files that were recently added to the system and then check the total size of folders where such a files were found. While the file you find using this method may be small, it can be part of a larger collection of files you have downloaded or installed.

I have written a [blog post that shows how to find large files and folders](https://blog.houdah.com/2015/11/find-large-files-os-x/). In the blog post I use [HoudahSpot](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/). Full disclosure: I am the developer of HoudahSpot.

You can use much the same techniques with Finder. HoudahSpot however makes it easier to set up the search. It also has the ability to show the “total size” of folders as a column in search results. You can also use HoudahSpot to quickly compute the [total size of a folder](https://blog.houdah.com/2015/12/total-size-of-a-folder/).

Both Finder and HoudahSpot search the Spotlight index. Neither will be able to find system files. Yet HoudahSpot will come up with search results that the Finder intentionally hides.

BTW, if disk space "went missing” just recently, try restarting your Mac. This will clean up temporary files left behind by applications.

Comment: Thanks for the information @PierreBernard. Wow, I'm surprised one can't search for folders by size with Finder. There must be some underlying reason why this isn't possible, since it would be so helpful. Any idea why my list of all files by size (first screen shot) omits unusual file types (e.g. `.pkg` or `.npy`)? Is this *also impossible* in Finder?

Comment: The Finder hides most of the content of the Library folders. That’s why you often see files missing from Finder search results.

Comment: The case of .pkg is interesting. There are two Uniform Type Identifies that map to the .pkg extension: com.apple.installer-package and com.apple.installer-package-archive. Autocomplete in the Finder search field tries to be helpful and suggest you search for “Kind:installer package archive”. This makes you miss out on the non-archive type.

Comment: OK but when I just search for all files, why are some files excluded. I want a single list of all file types at once. I'm not asking about searching for specific extensions.

Comment: Spotlight excludes certain file types and folders from indexing. This includes system folders and invisible files. Finder skips certain files and folders when searching the Spotlight index. This includes most of your Library folder. Unfortunately there is no documentation on what the Finder hides from view. If you want to find all files, you need a low-level tool that combs through all of the file system.

Comment: OK! Thank you @PierreBarnard for taking the time to explain. Now I see why you brought up a 3rd party option in the beginning. Apple must have some rationale for limiting to "common, every day" file types. If the user is filling a substantial fraction of their HD with "special" file types, then they probably will know how to write or find a way to look.

Comment: Try the following at the command line in Terminal.app: `find / -size +100M 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me what it does - before I type it? The `2>` and `/def/null` look mysterious! Is there a way to direct the output to a file instead of the screen so I can look at it "offline"?

Comment: You can learn more about the find command in its manual. Type `man find` to open the man pages. Hit space to scroll. Hit q to quit. I assume you are using the `bash` shell which has been the default on Mac for some years now. `2>` redirects the error output. `/dev/null` is a virtual file.  `2> /dev/null` makes error messages go nowhere so you see only standard output in the Terminal window. You can redirect standard output to a file by writing `> /path/to/file`. Be careful: this overwrites the file. Use `>> /path/to/file` to append.

Comment: Parallels (v10), in particular, sometimes sucks up my disk space until I reboot.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to search by size using Terminal (Confirmed working on Mojave).

No 3rd party tools or hacks.

Here is a command I used to look through and find largest folders taking my space away (run as root and the command to switch to root is: `sudo -i`):

```
du -k / | awk '$1 > 500000' | sort -nr
```

Once you get the list (ignore the 'Operation not permitted' since those are files you can't (shouldn't) mess with anyway) and look for the top ones.

Comment: Okay this is very helpful, *thank you!* Almost 2/3 of the paths begin with `/Users/name/Pictures/...` is there a way add something to  the bash line to omit those? I can paste the output as a python string and drop those lines no problem, I'm just curious if it's easy to do directly in the bash command.

Answer (score 1):

Mac's Finder search limits where your results come from. I'd recommend two solutions, both of which are free (one with a free trial).

The first is [EasyFind](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html) (free) from Devon Technologies and truly searches the entire directory of your Mac. It's vital for getting a true search on your Mac.

The second solution is very handy for finding the culprits of large HD space: [DaisyDisk](https://daisydiskapp.com/) (free trial). DaisyDisk will analyze a specified drive and then provide you with an interactive drill down to determine which files exactly are causing the issues.

Comment: There's also [GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net) freeware, which does a similar job to DaisyDisk.

Comment: This looks **more like an advertisement** than an answer @BenHolland. Please double check the last sentence of my question again, thanks!

Comment: Having read your last sentence again, the simple answer is "no", as the beginning of this answer mentions. The Finder will not search everywhere. That's why things like EasyFind exist.

Comment: When I worked at Apple, the notorious "how do I know what to delete when my drive is full?" came up constantly. Besides the About This Mac > Storage pane, Apple really doesn't provide any tools to resolve this issue, hence my answer above. I've helped hundreds of people resolve the issue, and the two items above are the most helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. This answer says "...limits where your results come from." Should it say "*...limits which file types it displays.*" instead? I think the issue is *file type* in my case. Finder certainly *does look* in that directory very nicely.

Comment: OK thanks @BenHolland for the info. In my case personally, I'm allergic to installing anything more than absolutely necessary on my computer. I'll have to find a workaround in the terminal.

Comment: @uhoh - It really doesn't like showing you results from 'hidden' structures. It really tries to be very 'user-level', which Is why I keep EasyFind close to hand always. It's not as fast as Spotlight, because it doesn't index, but at least it searches everywhere you ask it.

Comment: I just added another example @Tetsujin - I create six files and it shows all six when I look in the folder, but when I search, it skips the `.npy` and `.weird` just like it skips `.pkg` files (sometimes). Since `.pkg` and `.npy` could be numerous and large, I wish it wouldn't. Anyway thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest trying Disk Inventory X and it will find files and help you remove large ones: